# Cleaning Timestamp Data - Python

Tags: python, timestamp, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean timestamp data. 
I am trying to put them all in one format--Universal time format.
But some entries are in such format: 
11/20/2018 12:00 AM
and there seems to be some inputs with errors: 
20 ноября 2018 00:00

Do I loop within the column

for i in timestamp:
    ...?

if so how do I filter then convert these "errors" into the Universal time format? YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS UTC

I am planning on looping within the column

timestamp = df['timestamp'].values
for i in timestamp:
    ...?

Results should look like this:
2018-11-20 00:00:00 UTC
2018-11-20 00:00:00 UTC
2018-11-20 00:00:00 UTC
2018-11-20 00:00:00 UTC
2018-11-20 00:00:00 UTC
2018-11-20 00:00:00 UTC

Comment: [`dateutil.parser`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) would be good to start with.

Comment: Pandas also has a 'timezone aware' function that lets you switch to utc. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html